# I'm getting Http 400 Error from URLs string containing "%20" with Java Net URL

Tags: java, url, nio

Hey all trying to write a web scraper that downloads all the songs from this website
https://billwurtz.com/songs.html
but some of his older URLs contain spaces ("%20") such as `https://billwurtz.com/can%20i.mp3`. Which on his newer links he has changed to '-'.
Anyway, when I try to download these tracks I get a 400 Error (Bad Request Error) which makes me think that java is sending the request with   and not `%20`

```java
URL website = new URL("https://www.billwurtz.com/" + song);
Path out = Path.of("songs/" + song);
               
System.out.println(website.toString());
try (InputStream in = website.openStream()) {
  Files.copy(in, out, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
} catch (Exception e) {
  // missed.add(song + ":" + e.getMessage());
  throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
}
```

returns

```
https://www.billwurtz.com/can%20i.mp3
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://billwurtz.com/can i.mp3
```

I tried looking about but only came across issues created from the programmer trying to create a URL that contains   (spaces) but here it is clear that it is using `%20`

Thank you all for your time :)

Comment: what is `song` declaration looks like?

Comment: and what java version are you using

Comment: `Pattern link = Pattern.compile(".*HREF=\"(.*\\.mp3)\"");`
`Matcher m = link.matcher(line);` (line is one line from the HTML)
`String song = m.group(1)`
and I'm using java 15.0.2 2021-01-19

Comment: and an example failing value for song is `can%20i.mp3` and a passing value is `might-quit.mp3`